# React menu hamburger causes layout children to rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, hamburger-menu

I am using React and Material UI v5. I have a menu component inside my layout that has children. When clicking on the menu it causes the children to refresh. I have tried solving it by wrapping the children components in React.memo(child) but the result is still the same. What am I doing wrong?

*menu component*

```
const MyMenu = ({ menuAnchorEl, setMenuAnchorEl }) => {
    const menuOpen = Boolean(menuAnchorEl);

    const handleMenuClose = () => {
        setMenuAnchorEl(null);
    };

    const menuOptions = [
        {
            link: '/overview',
            Icon: Dashboard,
            label: 'Overview',
        },
    ];

    const MenuOption = ({
        link,
        Icon,
        label,
    }: {
        link: string;
        Icon: OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<unknown, 'svg'>> & {
            muiName: string;
        };
        label: string;
    }) => {
        return (
            <NavLink href={link}>
                <MenuItem>
                    <ListItemIcon>
                        <Icon color="secondary" fontSize="small" />
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText sx={{ color: 'text.primary' }}>
                        {label}
                    </ListItemText>
                    <Typography variant="body2"></Typography>
                </MenuItem>
            </NavLink>
        );
    };

    return (
        <Menu
            anchorEl={menuAnchorEl}
            open={menuOpen}
            onClose={handleMenuClose}
            variant="selectedMenu"
        >
            <MenuList>
                {menuOptions.map((n) => (
                    <MenuOption key={n.link} {...n} />
                ))}
            </MenuList>
        </Menu>
    );
};
```

*layout component*

```
const MyLayout = observer(({ children }: IProps) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [menuAnchorEl, setMenuAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(
        null,
    );

    return (
        <>
            <Hidden mdDown implementation="css">
                <InstallerMenu
                    menuAnchorEl={menuAnchorEl}
                    setMenuAnchorEl={setMenuAnchorEl}
                />
                <div className={classes.appFrame}>
                    <div className={classes.container}>{children}</div>
                </div>
            </Hidden>
        </>
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the `MenuOption` Component inside `MyMenu` and each time react re-render the main component `MyMenu` the `MenuOption` get re defined and cause all the children's to re-render again, in order to fix the issue you must take the `MenuOption` outside the main components and pass the required props to it, your code will look like this

alos read this [article](https://dev.to/borasvm/react-create-component-inside-a-component-456b) to know more why component inside component is bad

```
const MyMenu = ({ menuAnchorEl, setMenuAnchorEl }) => {
    const menuOpen = Boolean(menuAnchorEl);

    const handleMenuClose = () => {
        setMenuAnchorEl(null);
    };

    const menuOptions = [
        {
            link: '/overview',
            Icon: Dashboard,
            label: 'Overview',
        },
    ];

    return (
        <Menu
            anchorEl={menuAnchorEl}
            open={menuOpen}
            onClose={handleMenuClose}
            variant="selectedMenu"
        >
            <MenuList>
                {menuOptions.map((n) => (
                    <MenuOption key={n.link} {...n} />
                ))}
            </MenuList>
        </Menu>
    );
};


function MenuOption({requiredProps}){
return (
    <NavLink href={link}>
        <MenuItem>
            <ListItemIcon>
                <Icon color="secondary" fontSize="small" />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText sx={{ color: 'text.primary' }}>
                {label}
            </ListItemText>
            <Typography variant="body2"></Typography>
        </MenuItem>
    </NavLink>
);
 };
```

Comment: Hey Sarkar, Thanks for the insight. I tried your solution but the result is still the same

Comment: @KinaraNyakaru In that case please make a reproducible example on https://codesandbox.io/ so we can take a better look at the code